# how to use custom layout with ionic3 barcode-scanner plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, layout, barcode

I am using `ionic3`, I need to create a screen to scan `QRCode`/`Barcode` with this layout: [show model example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj0wr.png), Is there a possibility of `HTML` injection in this **plugin**?

**Documentation:**

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

**Useful links:**

https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview

[Get picture in Custom View Camera Preview Ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295654/get-picture-in-custom-view-camera-preview-ionic-3)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to build a custom layout using barcode-scanner but,

You can make a custom layout for QRcode scanner using the following plugin:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner